# How to send a "signal" from kernel module to user-space application?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, signals, interrupt

I have a Linux kernel module which contains the interrupt handler, and would like to somehow notify the user-space application after the interrupt was handled. Please tell me, how to do it?

Comment: Can we assume that you're talking about Linux?  Either way, please add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, we are talking about Linux, but I ran out of tags

Comment: You could, e.g., remove “hardware” in favour of “linux”. Hardware knowledge is not really important to answer this question.

Comment: @chirlu Okay I have done it. Please lets return to the question

Comment: The tags are important to get the right people to look at your question. See? Answers are coming. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can always use normal sockets, like UDP or UNIX.
- You can export this information via `/proc` or `/sys` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145943/communication-between-linux-kernel-and-user-space-program) question).
- You can use Netlink (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903572/linux-ways-to-communicate-with-kernel-module-from-user-space) question).

Comment: message queue, or shared memory?

Comment: You can use signals too to userspace :).. Only thing your kernel module should know is PID of the process which needs to trigger. I have used IOCTL to the kernel module to pass PID :).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [netlink](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356).

> Netlink socket is a special IPC used for transferring information
>   between kernel and user-space processes. It provides a full-duplex
>   communication link between the two by way of standard socket APIs for
>   user-space processes and a special kernel API for kernel modules.
>   Netlink socket uses the address family AF_NETLINK, as compared to
>   AF_INET used by TCP/IP socket. Each netlink socket feature defines its
>   own protocol type in the kernel header file include/linux/netlink.h.

Answer (score 0):

I'm directly answering this question as it's the top result in Google for "kernel send signal to user space".

I typically use signal to kill the userspace process to examine it's stack as it calls ioctls.  Typically the following works for me:

```
force_sig(SIGSEGV, current);
```